# Extract values from terminal

Tags: command-line

I need help to extract only the time's value when pinging using sed.

```
ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.11 (192.168.1.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.11: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.11: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.024 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.11: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms
```

So after using sed I would like to get the following output:

```
ping 192.168.1.1 | sed '???'
0.028
0.027
0.024
0.031
```

Thank you!

Comment: Hmm... a slightly harsh use of 'Duplicate' as this question does not ask for awk, it asks for sed...

Comment: @andrew.46 I gave a sed solution, so this is answered with sed. However, the main question (how can I get the time from ping) is indeed a duplicate. There's not much point in having two just because one happened to ask for sed. In any case, this is just closed, it won't be deleted, so the sed answer will still be here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `sed` you can do:

```
ping 192.168.1.1 | sed -n 's/.*time=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
```

That simply looks for the longest stretch of non-space after `time=`, uses parentheses to capture it so we can later refer to it as `\1` and just replaces everything on the line with whatever was captured. The `-n` (don't print by default) along with the `/p` (print if this worked) at the end of the substitution operator ensure we only print relevant lines.

I wouldn't use `sed` for this though, other tools are simpler here. For example:

1. grep

   ```
   ping 192.168.1.1 | grep -Po 'time=\K\S+'
   ```
2. Perl

   ```
   ping 192.168.1.1 | perl -lne '/time=(\S+)/ && print $1'
   ```
3. awk

   ```
   ping 192.168.1.1 | awk -F'[= ]' '/time=/{print $(NF-1)}'
   ```

Comment: @Ana.B You might consider accepting the answer by clicking on the gray tick. If you think it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

There are better solutions than sed for this one I suspect. The following solution uses cut and is perhaps not very elegant but it works well enough:

```
ping -c 4 -n google.com | cut -d '=' -s -f4 | cut -d ' ' -f1
```

Running this in real life reveals:

```
andrew@illium~$ ping -c 4 -n google.com | cut -d '=' -s -f4 | cut -d ' ' -f1
14.8
16.1
14.9
14.4

andrew@illium~$
```

Gotta love the command line :)

**Notes:**

1. For the `ping` command:

   - `-c 4`: Stop after sending 4 packets
   - `-n` : Give numeric info only, not the associated names for the host address
2. For the first `cut` command:

   - `-d '='`: Use the delimeter of the = sign
   - `-f4` : Select the 4th field
   - `-s` : Do not print lines not containing delimiters
3. For the second `cut` command:

   - `-d ' '` : Use the delimeter of a space ' '
   - `f1` : Select the first field